# How to animate a text based on scrolling progress

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, math, browser

The following scenario: The user is on a page and scrolling through the content when suddenly an element appears in the viewport, its child elements fly into the screen from different directions.

As soon as the element appears its children become visible in the viewport through animations and disappears again perfectly when leaving the viewport. The text is may larger than the viewport itself.

The respective start direction can be found as an attribute of the respective element. Due to some events the position is not calculated correctly. It seems that on square heights and latitudes everything works. See my comments in the javascript code. I actually don't know at this point whats wrong.

See my fiddle with sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/oqe145tv/23/

jQuery is used there: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js

```
<div class="marquee">
  <div class="marquee-row" data-position="start">
    <div class="marquee-row-data">
      <p class="marquee-row-data-text"><span>Mertingen</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-row-data">
      <p class="marquee-row-data-text"><span>Praha</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-row-data">
      <p class="marquee-row-data-text"><span>Budapest</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-row-data">
      <p class="marquee-row-data-text"><span>Bratislava</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-row-data">
      <p class="marquee-row-data-text"><span>Das ist ein cooler und langer Test</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="marquee-row" data-position="end">
    <div class="marquee-row-data">
      <p class="marquee-row-data-text"><span>Günzburg</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-row-data">
      <p class="marquee-row-data-text"><span>Wroclaw</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-row-data">
      <p class="marquee-row-data-text"><span>Opole</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="marquee-row-data">
      <p class="marquee-row-data-text"><span>Hanoi</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  padding: 30rem 0;
}

.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.marquee-row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
}

.marquee-row[data-position="end"] {
  float: right;
}

.marquee-row-data {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  position: relative;
}

.marquee-row-data:not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '/';
  color: black;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}

.marquee-row-data::after,
.marquee-row-data-text>* {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.marquee-row-data-text {
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: clip;
}

.marquee-row-data-text span {
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
}

.marquee-row-data-text a {
  color: red;
}
```

```
function run() {
  const marquees = $('.marquee');
  if (marquees.length === 0) return;

  const handleSliding = _ => {
    $(marquees).each((_, marquee) => {
      const rows = $(marquee).find('.marquee-row');
      if (rows.length === 0) return;

      const handler = entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            $(window).on('scroll.marquee', _ => {
              $(rows).each((i, row) => {
                const position = $(row).attr('data-position');
                if (!position) return;

                const elementPositionY = row.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                const percentHeight = 100 / window.innerHeight * elementPositionY;
                const startPos = 100 / window.innerWidth * $(row).innerWidth() * -1;

                // percentHeight = percentHeight < 0 ? 0 : percentHeight > 100 ? 100 : percentHeight;
                // fullWidth / window.innerHeight;
                // 100 / (fullWidth / (100 / window.innerHeight * elementPositionY));
                // 100 / ((fullWidth / 100) * (100 / window.innerHeight * elementPositionY));
                // fullWidth / (window.innerHeight + $(marquee).outerHeight())
                const fullWidth = window.innerWidth + $(row).innerWidth();
                const percentWidth = fullWidth / window.innerHeight;


                const percent = startPos + (percentWidth * percentHeight);
                $(row).css(position === 'start' ? 'left' : 'right', `${percent}vw`);
              });
            }).scroll();
          } else
            $(window).off('scroll.marquee');
        });
      };

      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handler);
      observer.observe(marquee);
    });
  };

  handleSliding();
}

run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rewriting the complete code I managed to fix it like the following:

```js
const run = _ => {
    const wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');
    if (wrappers.length === 0) return;

    document.addEventListener('scroll', _ => {
        wrappers.forEach(wrapper => {
            const items = wrapper.querySelectorAll('.item');
            if (items.length === 0) return;

            items.forEach((item, i) => {
                if (wrapper.offsetTop > window.scrollY + window.innerHeight || wrapper.offsetTop + wrapper.offsetHeight < window.scrollY) return;

                const position = item.getAttribute('data-position');
                if (!position) return;

                const faktor = 100 / window.innerWidth * ((window.innerWidth + item.offsetWidth) / 100);
                const screenHeight = window.innerHeight - item.offsetHeight;

                let scrollProgress = 100 - (100 / screenHeight * (item.offsetTop - window.scrollY));

                if (scrollProgress > 100) scrollProgress = 100;
                if (scrollProgress < 0) scrollProgress = 0;

                let startPos = 100 - 100 * faktor;

                if (position === 'right')
                    startPos = 100 * faktor - (100 + (100 * faktor));

                const progress = startPos + scrollProgress * faktor;
                item.style = `${position}: ${progress}vw`;
            });
        });
    });
};

run();
```

```css
body {
    padding: 1500px 0;
    background: #222;
}

.wrapper {
    background: orange;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 200px 0;
}

.item {
    background: green;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
    width: 500px;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
    width: 2500px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
    width: 1000px;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
    width: 750px;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
    width: 1800px;
}

.item:nth-child(6) {
    width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item" data-position="left"></div>
    <div class="item" data-position="right"></div>
    <div class="item" data-position="left"></div>
    <div class="item" data-position="left"></div>
    <div class="item" data-position="right"></div>
    <div class="item" data-position="right"></div>
</div>
```